# onLoadFinished() not getting called, but onCreateLoader() is called

Tags: fragmentpageradapter, android-cursorloader, android-loadermanager

I am using **CursorLoader** to load data from database inside my Fragment, which has a **RecyclerView**. This fragment is being used inside a ViewPager. The **ViewPager** is contained inside a ContainerFragment, which in turn is inside an Activity.

The ContainerFragment initializes first 4 loaders out of the 10 required in `onActivityCreated()`. From the log I can see that the loader(s) are in fact getting created. However, `onLoadFinished` is not getting called for any of the loaders.

Now the twist comes when I swipe through the ViewPager to the third fragment. Now I see the third loader's `onLoadFinished` getting called. Now this is probably not called from the fragment but from the PagerAdapter's `getItem()` method, which in addition to instantiating the fragments, also initializes loaders with their IDs in case they haven't been already.

**From all other questions on StackOverflow about onLoadFinished not getting called**, I have tried the following solutions which are not working for me:

1. Using `forceLoad()`
2. `this.getListView().refreshDrawableState();` -> not tried, and don't understand why this should work. Moreover, I am using RecyclerView.
3. "Importing the correct class" -> I am using AndroidX, and moreover, the loader does load sometimes. If it was the wrong class, it wouldn't have worked any time right?
4. "Fragment should use `SupportLoaderManager`" -> tried replacing in the fragment with `getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager`. For fragment I think it's just `getLoaderManager`. It was already working sometimes with just `getLoaderManager`. (No difference observed)

**`#onActivityCreated`**

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    startLoaders();
}
```

**`startLoaders()`**

```
private void startLoaders() {
    while(loaderSeqIndex < CATEGORIES.size() && loaderSeqIndex < 4) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("category", CATEGORIES.get(loaderSeqIndex));
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(loaderSeqIndex++, bundle, this);
    }
}
```

**LoaderCallbacks**

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, @Nullable Bundle args) {
    Timber.i("Loader created onCreateLoader called");
    CursorLoader loader = ArticleLoader.newCategorizedArticlesInstance(getContext(), args.getString("category"));
    loader.registerListener(id, new Loader.OnLoadCompleteListener<Cursor>() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadComplete(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
            int position = loader.getId();
            cursorHashMap.put(CATEGORIES.get(position), data);
            Timber.i("mPager.getCurrentItem(): " + mPager.getCurrentItem() + " position: " + position);
            if (position == mPager.getCurrentItem()) {
                ArticleListViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(ArticleListContainerFragment.this).get(ArticleListViewModel.class);
                model.setCursor(data);
            }
        }
    });
    return loader;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(@NonNull Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    int position = loader.getId();
    cursorHashMap.put(CATEGORIES.get(position), data);
    Timber.i("mPager.getCurrentItem(): " + mPager.getCurrentItem() + " position: " + position);
    if(position == mPager.getCurrentItem()) {
        ArticleListViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ArticleListViewModel.class);
        model.setCursor(data);
//            mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

**PagerAdapter's `#getView`**

```
private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
...
     @Override
     public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        ArticleListFragment fragment = ArticleListFragment.newInstance();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("category", CATEGORIES.get(position));
        bundle.putInt("id",position);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
//            fragment.setCursor(cursorHashMap.get(CATEGORIES.get(position)));
        return fragment;
    }
...
}
```

I was expecting timber to print from the `#onLoadFinished` method just to make sure that it's getting called, which isn't happening.

**Something weird that is happening is that:**
the `cursorHashMap` that I am using, get's properly populated I open the app a second time (when refresh doesn't happen). And the cursor get's populated without `#onLoadFinished` being called.